# How to keep piping output of a program to a python script, if the program is restarted

Tags: python, python-2.7, io

I know i can read the output of another script in Python by e.g. calling `some_program | print_input.py` and using `sys.stdin` in `print_input.py` like this:

```
import sys
if __name__=='__main__':
    while True:
        print sys.stdin.read(1024)
```

But is it also possible to restart `some_program` and still get its output without restarting `print_input.py`?

The idea is that the script `some_program` may crash, so that i will have to restart it, without loosing the current state of `print_input.py`.

Additional info that might be needed:

1. Launching `some_program` from within `print_input.py` using e.g. `subprocess` is not an option unfortunately.
2. Low latency requirements, so no (long) blocking calls.
3. The output of `some_program` is massive.
4. I can't modify `some_program`.

Comment: How massive is you output? What kind of data, how big and how often?

Comment: Did you mean: losing.. pet hate of mine... I'm thinking you'd need the active pid of your python script.. and do something like http://serverfault.com/questions/407902/write-to-the-stdin-of-a-running-process-with-the-same-effect-behaviour-of-direct?rq=1

Comment: @HarryPotfleur: The output is coded video, so a quite continuous data flow with >100 KB/s

Comment: 100kb/s is not that massive, you could save it on the HDD and re-open it with your other script?

Comment: That's an option, but wouldn't that introduce much more extra latency compared to piping it? So far, i do localhost TCP streaming for transferring the data, but want to switch to piping for a lower latency.

Comment: The 100KB/s (kilobytes) is also more of a minimum value. This can easily go up to ~750KB/s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elegant/usual solution would be to use named pipes. Create a pipe using mkfifo , pipe the output of `some_program` to it and the python script can just read from the pipe. Both program can be restarted without issues.

Im not sure about performance but no IO should be involved (even thought the pipe seems to be a file).

Another possibility would be to create a temporary file in a tmpfs or ramfs filesystem, have `some_program` write to it, and the python script can just repeatedly try reading. But IMO this is strictly worse than using pipes..

Comment: Managed to get it running with this approach, thanks!