# How to make ffmpeg write its output to a named pipe

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, pipe

I know i can make `ffmpeg` put its output to `stdout` and `stderr` using `pipe:1` and `pipe:2`, respectively, as `output_file` parameter. ([Docs](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#pipe))

But what about [named pipes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe), can i make it write to one?

If not, is there a way to redirect the data in `stdout` to a named pipe in Linux? (something like `ffmpeg <parameters> | pipe123`)

This question is a follow-up of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32563527/how-to-keep-piping-output-of-a-program-to-a-python-script-if-the-program-is-res).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could create a named pipe first and have `ffmpeg` write to it using the following approach:

`ffmpeg` output to named pipe:

```
# mkfifo outpipe

# ffmpeg -i input_file.avi -f avi pipe:1 > outpipe
FFmpeg version 0.6.5, Copyright (c) 2000-2010 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jan 29 2012 17:52:15 with gcc 4.4.5 20110214 (Red Hat 4.4.5-6)
...
[avi @ 0x1959670]non-interleaved AVI
Input #0, avi, from 'input_file.avi':
  Duration: 00:00:34.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1433 kb/s
    Stream #0.0: Video: cinepak, yuv420p, 320x240, 15 tbr, 15 tbn, 15 tbc
    Stream #0.1: Audio: pcm_u8, 22050 Hz, 1 channels, u8, 176 kb/s
Output #0, avi, to 'pipe:1':
  Metadata:
    ISFT            : Lavf52.64.2
    Stream #0.0: Video: mpeg4, yuv420p, 320x240, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 15 tbn, 15 tbc
    Stream #0.1: Audio: mp2, 22050 Hz, 1 channels, s16, 64 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0.0 -> #0.0
  Stream #0.1 -> #0.1
Press [q] to stop encoding
frame=  510 fps=  0 q=11.5 Lsize=    1292kB time=33.96 bitrate= 311.7kbits/s
video:1016kB audio:265kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead 0.835379%
```

reading `outpipe` named pipe (`Python` example):

```
# python -c "import os; fifo_read = open('outpipe', 'r', 0); print fifo_read.read().splitlines()[0]"
RIFFAVI LIST<hdrlavih8j...
...
```

-- ab1

Answer (score 2):

@ab77 answer is spot on except for one *major* thing that I encountered myself.  I do not know if this happens on Linux or other *nix'es but on Mac OS X if you do not put the appropriate extension on the pipe name then it will not pipe.  So if the output format is *mpeg* then the pipe shold be name *outpipe.mpg* for instance.

Comment: I faced with this issue to. I tied to add extension but it doesn't help me.
# ffmpeg -f u16le -i hi.wav pipe:1  > outpipe.wav still returns error "pipe:1: Invalid argument"

Comment: @MaxKonin I think it may depend on what flavor of Unix you are on.  I know on Mac OS X pipe:1 worked for me.  If you do an ls -l on the pipe file it should have permissions -> prw-r--r--.  It also may be necessary to have some other process reading from the pipe.

Comment: The error was in the sequence of arguments.  # ffmpeg -i hi.wav -f u16le  pipe:1 > outpipe.wav. Works fine

Comment: You need `-f <format>` before the output to tell ffmpeg what format to use. Usually it can guess from the file extension, but in this case there is none.