# Access pixel data of each frame of a video in Ruby

Tags: ruby, macos, image-processing, ffmpeg

I want to be able to read/stream a video with Ruby, on Mac, and be able to get access to the pixel data for each frame.

## What I've tried

- https://github.com/streamio/streamio-ffmpeg

  It's good at splitting the video into frames, but I don't know how to get access to the pixel data without saving each frame as an image first (or if it's possible at all).

---

```
require 'streamio-ffmpeg'
movie = FFMPEG::Movie.new("flakes.mp4")

movie.screenshot("screenshots/screenshot_%d.jpg", { custom: %w(-vf crop=60:60:10:10), vframes: (movie.duration).to_i, frame_rate: movie.frame_rate/24 }, { validate: false })`
```

---

- https://github.com/wedesoft/hornetseye-ffmpeg

  This seemed to have so much potential, but I don't think it's maintained anymore, and it's not meant to be used on MacOS really, so I'm having issues installing it there (headers not found and such, and no way to configure it afaik).

Any idea what tool or method I could use for this use case?

Comment: I would try to get the ffmpeg wrapper to write the screenshot to a file stream (rather than using a file name). Then you could read it directly into Ruby using whatever image library and avoid saving/loading on disk. Looking at the source of streamio-ffmpeg, it's a pretty thin wrapper around the command line so it should be pretty easy,

Comment: All the wrapper is doing is making it easier to pass options to the command line tool. So I would need ffmpeg to support this, and I dont think it does (or I couldnt find it). It does give a way to stream a video out to a server, so I think that might be the way to go... I was hoping there was another simple library that could do this.

Comment: At the very least you can make ffmpeg write to a fifo. It will think it's writing a normal file but you can read it directly into ruby.

Comment: You mean something like using `mkfifo my_fifo`, and then having ffmpeg write in this named pipe, and "reading" from my script? I just dont know how to get ffmpeg to output into this pipe. `ffmpeg -i mypic.jpg > my_fifo` would only work if ffmpeg was outputing stuff to stdout, no? If it's literally writing to the file mypic.jpg internally, I dont see how I can change that. If you know of a specific solution, please let me know.

Comment: @Max https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32584220/how-to-make-ffmpeg-write-its-output-to-a-named-pipe turns out, I just had to google the right thing, and you definitely put me on the right track. Thanks. (Feel free to post any answer related to that and I'll accept it).

Comment: Glad it helped. Answer posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have ffmpeg available (streamio-ffmpeg just wraps command line calls to ffmpeg), you can create a named pipe with [`File.mkfifo`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/File.html#method-c-mkfifo) and have ffmpeg write its screenshots to that pipe.

Then open the pipe in Ruby like you would any normal file and you can read the screenshot images directly from ffmpeg without them being transferred to/from disk. Parse the pixel data with the Ruby gem of your choice.

Comment: Could you elaborate some on this?  I think I understand creating the named pipe and feeding it to ffmpeg, but so far I can only read back a single screenshot written to the pipe.  I can't seem to figure out how to say like File.open run this block for each file in the stream.